# Google sheet query range resets to A:A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheet that is using a query to read in a set of CSV files every hour. The files have data in columns A-F. Sometimes my query statement changes from range A:F to A:A With no manual intervention. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: This is too obscure without any sample data or a way to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

to make sure it never happens you can put your range into indirect like:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT("A:F"), .....
```